# Salesforce Marketing Cloud JB Split based on date - specific time

Tags: journeybuilder, marketing-cloud

I have a salesforce campaign entry event. I want to build a journey builder split based on a date/time field. However, it seems that the Journey Builder split activity based on date only recognizes the date, and not necessarily the time, even if the time is populated. Is there a workaround for this that I'm unaware of? Right now my best workaround is to create multiple journeys with filtered data extensions based off the sync'd Salesforce object.

Answer (score 0):

the below example from salesforcefan.com to send out email hourly by leveraging on wait by attribute activity could be the alternative solution to your question.

[https://www.salesforcefan.com/post/dynamic-salesforce-marketing-cloud-email-send-based-upon-country][1]